ASP.NET Web API auth
I have to login methods on my website but I have a problem: when I login with normal authentication, I need to login in database like I have multiple servers, I choose one I log in on one of those but the problem is the key because when I log in with database I need to store a claim that is the username so I can use on other stored procedures because to make two token is not a good solution how can I maintain to refresh the claim or maybe refresh the token so it doesn't affect the log in.
I tried to store it in headers but it didn't, tried to make two Authentication tokens but that is to much complex and to many validation
Login:
if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
{
    var existingToken = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingToken))
    {
        var tokenStoreService = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenStoreService>();
        tokenStoreService.AddTokenToBlacklist(existingToken);
    }

    // Retrieve the connection string for the user
    var connectionString = GetUserConnectionString(user);

    var token = GenerateJwtToken(user, connectionString, model.RememberMe);

    return Ok(new { Token = token });
}

return Unauthorized(new { Result = "Invalid login attempt" });

Token generator:
var claims = new[]
             {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, new DateTimeOffset(kosovoTime).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, new DateTimeOffset(kosovoTime).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Actor, AesEncryptionHelper.Encrypt(connectionString)),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "")
             };

var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

var expiration = rememberMe ? kosovoTime.AddDays(7) : kosovoTime.AddDays(1);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
     issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
     audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
     claims: claims,
     notBefore: kosovoTime,
     expires: expiration,
     signingCredentials: creds);

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

if (rememberMe)
{
     var tokenStoreService = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenStoreService>();
     tokenStoreService.SetExtendedExpiration(tokenString, expiration);
}

return tokenString;

Database login:
 var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

 if (userId == null)
 {
     return Unauthorized(new { Result = "User not found" });
 }

 var connectionDetails = await _context.Connections
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ApplicationUserId == userId);

 if (connectionDetails == null)
 {
     return BadRequest(new { Result = "No connection details found for the specified user" });
 }

 var decryptedPassword = AesEncryptionHelper.Decrypt(connectionDetails.Password);

 var dynamicConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
 {
     DataSource = connectionDetails.Server,
     InitialCatalog = connectionDetails.Database,
     UserID = connectionDetails.Username,
     Password = decryptedPassword,
     TrustServerCertificate = true
 }.ConnectionString;

 var sql = $"EXEC [{connectionDetails.Database}].dbo.TryWebLogin @CurrentCulture, @OnlineVersion, @MacAddress, @Username, @Password";

 try
 {
     using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dynamicConnectionString))
     {
         using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
         {
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCulture", model.CurrentCulture);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnlineVersion", model.OnlineVersion);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MacAddress", model.MacAddress);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", model.Username);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", model.Password);

             await connection.OpenAsync();
             var result = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();

             if (result != null && Convert.ToInt32(result) == 1)
             {
                 return Ok(new { Result = "Login successful" });
             }
             else
             {
                 return Unauthorized(new { Result = "Invalid login attempt" });
             }
         }
     }
 }
 catch (SqlException ex)
 {
     _logger.LogError(ex, "Connection failed");
     return StatusCode(500, new { Result = "Connection failed" });
 }


Can you not just obtain the currently authenticated user from the HttpContext?

have tried it but it doesn't work

How does it not work, what did you try?

tried to add this on header but I'm always getting null value

You don't need to add it to a header, use the HttpContext to obtain information about the currently authenticated user. I also questoin the business case for having unique connection strings per user, why not just limit the operations they can perform?

like the normal login doesn't have anything to do with the login that is in database, this login of database limit the operations that they will perform

I understand that. Tying a user to a connection string doesn't feel right in my opinion. Instead have an agnostic connection string and impose limitations on a per user basis in the code.

okay bro i will consider this to use
